# Use textarea resize functionality without ruining layout

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table (yep, I know, but I have no control over whether to use a table or not), with each cell containing a div and within each div is a form element. The tables width is set to 100% width with CSS. All of the divs within the table cells have 5px margin to give some space. All of the form elements (inputs, selects, textareas) are set to 100% width also, so that the entire screen is used (not my idea at all!).

What I need to do is on hover of a div in a table cell remove the textarea from the doc flow via absolute positioning (to restore its resizing functionality without messing up the layout), give it a higher z-index and then on mouseleave return it to its original state.

What I have at the moment is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('table tr td div div.textareaHolder').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({
        position : 'absolute',
        zIndex : '100'
        });
});
    $('table tr td div div.textareaHolder').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
        position : 'static',
        width : '100%',
        height : '100%',
        zIndex : ''
        });
});
});
```

Also returning the textarea to its original size.

Comment: Why is your table containing textarea inside it?

Comment: Rather than trying to manipulate your CSS with JS, just add/remove a `class` on hover. Would be good to see what you're trying to do on jsFiddle or something.

Comment: Vivek Dragon - its a large form layout including textareas

Comment: @Ed-M is correct you have to use a class js is not necessary here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood the question correctly; you want to 'expand' the `textarea` when hovered over and fall back to its original state?

Made a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeErF/11/)**, hope that helps

Edit:

Ok, in Firefox, **[this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeErF/27/)** will work just fine, but in Chrome, the textarea gets seizures, since when you resize it, your mouse cursor changes its position slightly around the boundaries, firing up the hover states multiple times.

You could disable user resize with `textarea { resize: none; }` entirely, or target only Chrome with

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   textarea { resize: none; }
}
```

(or via [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)) and leave the resize on for Firefox.

Comment: what I am looking for is indeed very similar to the above fiddle but with the textarea returning to original size on mouseout, thereby not ruining the overall layout.

Comment: the above example works for me, are you experiencing issues with it?

Comment: Hi Metzger, I am using firefox and the fiddle's textarea doesnt return to original size on mouseout. Whoops, sorry, it does on mouseout but what I am trying to achieve is that a user could resize the textarea using the bottom right handle whilst using it and then on mouseout it returns to its original size.

Comment: Thanks Metzger, that's as close as I need for now.

Comment: sorry i couldn't make this 100% work, mayhaps i'll think of something

Answer (score 2):

you can try this class instead of js

```
 .txtholder
    {
     position:static;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
    }

   .txtholder:hover
     {
      position:absolute;
      z-index:100;
      }
```

Comment: Hi Vivek and @Ed-M, I have tried the css method and the add class method, which both work fine apart from one point, the textarea (and div containing it), dont return to their original width and height. Any ideas?

Comment: you can try onfocus instead of hover

Comment: Hi Vivek, onfocus is raw javascript isnt it? Im totally useless with raw javascript, how would this be done?

Comment: There is a :focus pseudo class:  `.txtholder:focus`

Comment: Hi cimmanon, I have tried :focus and this works as expected but when focus is removed the textarea does not return to its original state, which is what I am trying to achieve